# To get all the two letters directories using terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

Suppose I have directories like this:

```
A9
d0
23
12
k3
Folder1
Folder2
```

I want to find all the directories with just two letter, can anyone give the regular expression for listing all the directories.

Note: I have folders of only the letters A-Z, a-z, and numbers 0-9 combined in 2 letters.

```
$ ls <some command>

A9
d0
23
12
k3
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the shell uses wildcard (or "glob") patterns to match filenames, not regular expressions. They're just similar enough to be very confusing if you don't keep the distinction clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `??` to get all 2 character entries:

```
ls -ld ??
```

`?` matches any single character in shell glob

To list only directories use:

```
ls -ld ??/
```

Trailing `/` lists directories only.

Comment: This also shows files, perhaps you want `ls -ld ??/` (which will add a slash to your hits) or `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "??" -type d`.

Comment: Thanks @WalterA. I have edited it in my answer also